# How to solve TS "Duplicate identifier" clash with VSCode extension file?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following type in my .ts file:

```ts
type Permissions = 'admin' | 'user' | 'manager'
```

And VSCode shows me the following error:

```
Duplicate identifier 'Permissions'.ts(2300)
lib.dom.d.ts(10696, 11): 'Permissions' was also declared here.
lib.dom.d.ts(10700, 13): and here.
```

This `lib.dom.d.ts` file is located here:
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts`

I tried to solve it by adding `include` and `exclude` configurations to my `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
"include": ["src/**/*"],
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

I also tried to add `"**/*.d.ts"` to the `exclude` part. Restarted VSCode several times, after every attempt to fix it. Nothing worked for me.

After searching for a solution, the only thing that did work was adding `export {}` at the end of my .ts file.

I'm not a big fan of this solution, don't like the idea of adding an extra line of code to export an empty object. Any idea how to fix this clash without this export?

Comment: Rename your type to something else. Besides, why *not* export your type? You should be anyways. I'd find it a pain if I had a type available everywhere in my project. For example, what if I need to name something else the same name? Or when there is a built-in type or class? Then what would I do?